# Autowired JpaRepository Save Ignored in custom FieldSetMapper

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-data-jpa

In brief, I am trying to use JpaRepositories in spring batch related classes. But due to some reason, only selects are working but Insert/updates are ignored.

I have a custom `FieldSetMapper` as below,

```
@Component
@StepScope // I have not seen step scope is used as this  way!
public class ItemFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<CategoryItem> {

        private CSVSchema schema;

        private Task task;

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LocalPersist.class.getName());


        @Autowired 
        private CSVColumnDao csvColumnDao;


        @Autowired
        private BasisCategoryDao basisCategoryDao;

        @Override
        public BasisCategoryItem mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {

           // csvColumnDao.save(someobject) // This is ignored
        }
}
```

Since I have to start the job asynchronously (Job is started form controller method)

I created a custom DefaultBatchConfigurer as below,

```
@Component
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ProductImportBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor; // This is coming form another bean defined in another configuration class.

    /*@Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;*/

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Override
    protected JobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {

        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(super.getJobRepository());
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {

        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(dropDatabasePopulator(), dataSource);
        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(createDatabasePopulator(), dataSource);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setDataSource(dataSource);

    }

    private DatabasePopulator dropDatabasePopulator() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.setContinueOnError(true);
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql"));
        return databasePopulator;
    }

    private DatabasePopulator createDatabasePopulator() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.setContinueOnError(true);
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql"));
        return databasePopulator;
    }

}
```

This is my Application class,

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { BatchAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        pool.setCorePoolSize(6);
        pool.setMaxPoolSize(30);
        pool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
        return pool;
    }

}
```

**What I have figured so far:**

I went through many documentation to get my scenario working. [This](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2363) is the closest I got.

The issue is to do with `@EnableBatchProcessing`. It creates its own `DataSourceTransactionManager` which has no clue about jpa/hibernate and ignore inserts/updates.

As the suggested solution,

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(DataSource dataSource, EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new BasicBatchConfigurer(dataSource, entityManagerFactory);
}
```

This seems to be not working because the constructor changed in newer versions.

It seems like, I have to get rid of the `@EnableBatchProcessing` and get the same transaction manager to work both in application and batch contexts.

**Here are some trial and errors,**

If I keep the `@EnableBatchProcessing`  and use `@EnableAutoConfiguration (exclude = { BatchAutoConfiguration.class })`

The Batch tables are created and application runs correctly, But during the run time I get the following.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(AdvisedSupport.java:487) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:193) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.getTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.getTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.getTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
```

Here is the properties file I am using,

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db

spring.datasource.username =root
spring.datasource.password =root

spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 3600
spring.datasource.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 3600
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true


spring.jpa.database = MYSQL

spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto =update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.batch.job.enabled=false   

spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

But when I comment `@EnableBatchProcessing` the application complains for

`JobBuilderFactory`  bean and etc. It seems like use of same transaction manager is not a practice and I have not see auto wiring of Jpa Repositories in batch related classes (Eg, ItemWriters and Readers etc.). But I want this scenario to work since this is a migration from a different implementation to spring batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused with the injecting jpa transaction manager into the spring batch. This is how I was able to do it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ProductImportBatchConfig implements BatchConfigurer {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(DefaultBatchConfigurer.class);

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;

    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    protected ProductImportBatchConfig() {
    }

    @Override
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() {
        return jobRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Override
    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() {
        return jobExplorer;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {

        if (this.dataSource == null) {
            logger.error(null, new Throwable("This is not acceptable"));
        }
        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(dropDatabasePopulator(), this.dataSource);
        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(createDatabasePopulator(), this.dataSource);

        this.dataSource = dataSource;

        EntityManagerFactory object = entityManagerFactory.getObject();
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(object);

        this.transactionManager = jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            if (dataSource == null) {
                logger.warn("No datasource was provided...using a Map based JobRepository");

                if (this.transactionManager == null) {
                    this.transactionManager = new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
                }

                MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(
                        this.transactionManager);
                jobRepositoryFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
                this.jobRepository = jobRepositoryFactory.getObject();

                MapJobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactory = new MapJobExplorerFactoryBean(jobRepositoryFactory);
                jobExplorerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
                this.jobExplorer = jobExplorerFactory.getObject();
            } else {
                this.jobRepository = createJobRepository();

                JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
                jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
                jobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
                this.jobExplorer = jobExplorerFactoryBean.getObject();
            }

            this.jobLauncher = createJobLauncher();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BatchConfigurationException(e);
        }
    }

    public JobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    public JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    // Batch related scripts
    private DatabasePopulator dropDatabasePopulator() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.setContinueOnError(true);
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql"));
        return databasePopulator;
    }

    private DatabasePopulator createDatabasePopulator() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.setContinueOnError(true);
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql"));
        return databasePopulator;
    }
}
```